# Duplicate value when using Macro in switch case

Tags: c, macros, switch-statement

I am trying to make a switch case where the case is the result of a macro but when compiling the code, I get the errors "previously used here" and "duplicate value"

I do not understand when since I made sure that the results of the macro are always different.

Here is the code I tried out

```
#define MACROTEST(a, b) (a<<2 + b)

switch (MACROTEST(input_string[0], input_string[1])) {
                            case (MACROTEST('a', 'c')):
                            {
                                /*some code*/
                            } break;
                            case(MACROTEST('g', 'e')):
                            {
                                /*some code*/
                            } break;
                            case(MACROTEST('s', 'e')):
                            {
                                /*some code*/
                            } break;
                            case(MACROTEST('g', 'm')):
                            {
                                /*some code*/
                            } break;
                            case(MACROTEST('s', 'b')):
                            {
                                /*some code*/
                            } break;
                            case(MACROTEST('g', 'r')):
                            {
                                /*some code*/
                            } break;
                            case(MACROTEST('s', 'r')):
                            {
                                /*some code*/
                            } break;
                            default: {
                                /*some code*/
                            }
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Hint: Is `a<<2 + b` the same as `(a<<2) + b` or the same as `a<<(2 + b)`

Comment: Turn up the compiler warnings, pay attention to them, and when in doubt in a macro add more parenthesis. https://godbolt.org/z/jPb9aPdjf

Comment: Why try to "save" 6 bits of an integer value? There'd be zero chance of hash collisions of two characters with `#define MAC(a,b) ( ((a)<<8 | (b) )`

Comment: I changed the macro to this and it works now. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

The macro is sloppily written.

1. You most likely intended it to work like this? `((a<<2) + b)` It doesn't, since binary addition has higher precedence than shift.
2. As told in any C programming book, you must always surround function-like macro parameters with parenthesis, to avoid similar precedence hiccups.

So I think the macro you are looking for is:

```
#define MACROTEST(a, b) ( ((a) << 2) + (b) )
```